# Get total of all input values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need the total of all the values from my input. The result must be displayed in the input field total that is `readonly`.

The user can enter 1 or more values. The problem is that my `var` value is not correct. I'd also like to know how I can return the value immediately by `onchange`?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div#example input").change(function() {
    var value = '';    
    $("div#example input[name!=total]").each(function() {
      value += $(this).val();      
    });
    console.log("value after each: " + value);
  });
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="example">
   <input type="text" size="5" id="value1" name="value1" />
   <input type="text" size="5" id="value2" name="value2" />
   <input type="text" size="5" id="value3" name="value3" />
   <input type="text" size="5" id="value4" name="value4" />
   <input type="text" size="5" id="value5" name="value5" />
   <input type="text" size="5" id="total" readonly="readonly" class="bckground" name="total" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div#example id^='value'").change(function() {
        var value = 0;

        $("div#example input[name!=total]").each(function() {
            var i = parseInt($(this).val());

            if (!isNaN(i))
            {
                value += i;
            }
        });

        $('#total').val(value);
    });
})
```

Comment: Bobby I'm trying to follow this, can you please add some context to the implementation? Will this run each time an input field is updates (without hitting submit)?

Comment: @square_eyes: yes, the function passed to change() will execute whenever any of those inputs changes, although bear in mind that javascript interprets 'change' as 'loses focus with a new value' for text inputs - i.e. after you type a number, THEN move out of the input field, the change event triggers.

Answer (score 2):

use += parseInt($(this).val());

Comment: and how can i return the value?

Comment: NB - fails on the empty inputs, so you need to use isNan() to check for that (and other spurious input) - see my answer for details

Answer (score 1):

```
var sum = 0;  
$('input[id^=value]').each (function(){ sum+=$(this).val(); });
$('#total').val( sum );
```

:]

Comment: Without converting the results of val() to a numeric value, this will perform string concatenation which is not what was required.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be closer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#example value").change(function() {
    var total = 0;    
    $("#example value").each(function() {
      total += parseInt($(this).val());      
    });
    window.console && console.log("value after each: " + total);
  });
})

</script> 

<div id="example">
   <input type="text" size="5" class="value" name="value1" />
   <input type="text" size="5" class="value" name="value2" />
   <input type="text" size="5" class="value" name="value3" />
   <input type="text" size="5" class="value" name="value4" />
   <input type="text" size="5" class="value" name="value5" />
   <input type="text" size="5" id="total" readonly="readonly" class="bckground" name="total" />
</div>
```

Your original selector for $.change() was including the total box, which I suspect you don't want.

Am I correct in guessing you want to add numbers?  Your original 'value' variable was a string.

And BTW, it's safer to use the 'window.console && console.log' idiom, since there won't be a console variable for many users.  (Though I bet that line was only there for debugging.)

**EDIT**

Added parseInt() based on other suggestions.

Comment: 'suspect' - but you're not sure ;-) I'm wondering if change() actually fires when the value is changed programatically, using the val() function. It doesn't *appear* to for me

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery form serialization:

```
alert($("form_id").serialize());
```

There is also a comparison for different serialization types: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/comp/